# Which scriptures contain information about Stri Rajya?

Tags: scripture, puranas, history, women, smriti

Stri Rajya is a matriarchal kingdom located somewhere in [Uttarpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uttarapatha) and mentioned in several Hindu Scriptures like [Kama Sutra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kama_Sutra) and Sanskrit works (based on Hindu Scriptures), like [Raghuvamsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raghuva%E1%B9%83%C5%9Ba) and [Rajatarangini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rajatarangini).

Information about it is relatively scarce on the internet and even Wikipedia doesn't have an article on it.

I'd like to know the list of all scriptures which mention Stri Rajya or anything related to it.

Comment: The books you mentioned are not Hindu scriptures. They are poetic work, chronicle and treat written by Hindus in Sanskrit. They are not religious texts. You should modify as works not scriptures.

Comment: It is very good question because Hinduism consists also of artha and kama along with dharma. Also one of the book is related to itihasa so they indeed are useful texts helpful hindu history and way of life and human behavior

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Kama Sutra is indeed a religious text, and that too, quite ancient. Rajatarngini is an Itihaas text based on several Puranas. I have modified the question a little bit though.

Comment: Interesting question.. Stri Rajya would be somewhat akin to the concept of the Amazons from Greek Mythology!

Answer (score 6):

I have found two evidences in Mahabharata where Stri Rajya (Kingdom of women) is mentioned.

1. > 'That prosperity which the sons of Pritha had acquired at Indraprastha, and which, unobtainable by other kings, was beheld by me at the Rajasuya sacrifice, at which, besides, I saw all kings, even those of the Vangas and Angas and Paundras and Odras and Cholas and Dravidas and Andhakas, and the chiefs of many islands and countries on the sea-board as also of frontier states, including the rulers of the Sinhalas, the barbarous mlecchas, the natives of Lanka, and all the kings of the West by hundreds, and all the chiefs of the sea-coast, and the kings of the Pahlavas and the Daradas and the various tribes of the Kiratas and Yavanas and Sakras and the Harahunas and Chinas and Tukharas and the Sindhavas and the Jagudas and the Ramathas and the Mundas and **the inhabitants of the kingdom of women** and the Tanganas and the Kekayas and the Malavas and the inhabitants of Kasmira, afraid of the prowess of your weapons, present in obedience to your invitation, performing various offices,--that prosperity, O king, so unstable and waiting at present on the foe, I shall restore to thee, depriving thy foe of his very life. I shall, O chief of the Kurus, assisted by Rama and Bhima and Arjuna and the twins and Akrura and Gada and Shamva and Pradyumna and Ahuka and the heroic Dhrishtadyumna and the son of Sisupala, slay in battle in course of a day Duryodhana and Karna and Dussasana and Suvala's son and all others who may fight against us. And thou shalt, O Bharata, living at Hastinapura along with thy brothers, and snatching from Dhritarashtra's party the prosperity they are enjoying, rule this earth.' [Mahabharata, Vana Parva: Indralokagamana Parva, SECTION LI](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03051.htm)
2. > "Narada said, 'Having thus obtained weapons from him of Bhrigu's race, Karna began to pass his days in great joy, in the company of Duryodhana, O bull of Bharata's race! Once on a time, O monarch, many kings repaired to a self-choice at the capital of Chitrangada, the ruler of the country of the Kalingas. The city, O Bharata, full of opulence, was known by the name of Rajapura. Hundreds of rulers repaired thither for obtaining the hand of the maiden. Hearing that diverse kings had assembled there, Duryodhana. also, on his golden car, proceeded thither, accompanied by Karna. When the festivities commenced in that self-choice, diverse rulers, O best of kings, came thither for the hand of the maiden. There were amongst them Sisupala and Jarasandha and Bhishmaka and Vakra, and Kapotaroman and Nila and Rukmi of steady prowess, **and Sringa who was ruler of the kingdom females**, and Asoka and Satadhanwan and the heroic ruler of the Bhojas. [Mahabharata, Santi Parva: Rajadharmanusasana Parva, SECTION IV](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a004.htm)